# vue: forward default properties values in child components

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue (2.x) application. I'm currently trying to forward some properties from the parent component to the child component. Since I don't always need those values to be set, I have also added a default value:

Component script:

```
props: {
    ...
    center: {
        type: Object,

        default: () ⇒ {
            Object.assign({
                latitude: 50,
                longitude: 50,
            });
        },
    },
},
data() {
    return {
        localCenter: this.center,
    };
},
```

component template:

```
 <google-map
     :center="localCenter"
     ...
 </google-map>
```

In this case I expect `localCenter` to equal `latitude: 50, longitude: 50` if the property `center` has not been set. But the value is undefined.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your example is a bit confusing. Does the template that you show is the in the parent component ? And the code the child component ?

Comment: Yes, all the code is from the same component. The child component (google-map) just need to receive `center`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply missed to return the object from default:

```
    default: () ⇒ {
        return Object.assign({
            latitude: 50,
            longitude: 50,
        });
    },
```

Comment: Why so complicated ? Is there any advantage Object.assign? Or making this a function ?

Comment: For what I know there is no advantage, it answer just adding the missing piece that make work the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try just returning  an object. Why make things complicated?

**code**

```
Vue.component('google-map', {
  template: `<div>{{center}}</div>`,
  props: {
    center: {
      type: Object,
      default : {                    
        latitude: 50,
        longitude: 50,
      },
    }
  }
});
vm = new Vue({el:"#vueRoot"})
```

[**working fiddle using default**](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/3z1dphmr/16/)

[and the same thing passing a prop](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/3z1dphmr/17/)